# Count the depth of a specific element in a nested list

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to get the count of certain element's level in a nested list.

```
my_list = ["a", ["b", ["c", "d"], "e"], "f", ["g", ["h"]]]
```

To get the level of the element "e", I've tried to make a function for recursion but failed...

```
def get_level(letter, my_list):
    cnt = 0
    for sub_list in my_list:
        if letter in sub_list:
            cnt += 1
            return cnt
        else:
            get_level(letter, sub_list)

letter = "e"
print(get_level(letter, my_list))
```

The result should be `2`.

Please let me know if there is any way for it.

Comment: Have you considered recursion?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `1`? You are starting from `0`

Comment: This answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59588104/6660373 .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Find the "depth" of an element in list in a recursive loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59583113/python-find-the-depth-of-an-element-in-list-in-a-recursive-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got something like this:

```
def find_e(arr, index):
  if 'e' in arr:
    return index
  else:
    for element in arr:
      if isinstance(element, list):
        return find_e(element, index + 1)

my_list = ["a", ["b", ["c", "d"], "e"], "f", ["g", ["h"]]]
print('Index is: ',find_e(my_list, 0))
```